# Using Ringtones as Custom Push notification sounds for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Facebook and Twitter enable users to use ringtones as push notification sounds (for [things like](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27704/how-can-i-change-notification-sounds-on-ios) *Tweet*) on iPhones. Which are not bundled on the app, as the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6) for custom notification sound suggests.

Is this a special privilege for Twitter and Facebook apps, or is there a way to get such settings as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use custom ringtones as your app push notification sounds, this is a special feature for Twitter & Facebook.

You can only custom alert sounds by bundled audio file, and special sound name in payload.

Comment: you can't say something without proper source declaration where you got it from. Any official link and excerpt would be helpful.